# npm failed with error code: 1 in azure devops testing pipeline

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops

**reference:**

https://medium.com/@flu.lund/automated-angular-unit-testing-on-visual-studio-team-services-22c03497265c

I have refer above blog link and followed step to Automated Angular Unit Testing and publish test Result.

as per blog guideline i have followed below step.

**step 1**

Installed below packages.

1. npm install phantomjs-prebuilt --save-dev
2. npm install karma-phantomjs-launcher --save-dev
3. npm install karma-junit-reporter --save-dev

**step 2**

Then i have added some configuration in karma.conf.js

1. require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'), // <- Add plugin
2. require('karma-junit-reporter'), // <- Add plugin
3. browsers: ['Chrome', 'PhantomJS'], // <- Add browser

**step 3**

Then i added script in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "test-single-headless": "ng test --single-run=true --browsers=PhantomJS --reporters=progress,junit",
    ...
  },
```

**step 4**

I added below three line in polyfills.ts file

```
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
```

**step 5**

Added pipeline task you can see in below screenshot.

[image]

**step 6**

after setup all configure all thing as par blog guideline finally i run build.

**getting issue is**

Then i go to the result log it work form first task to build task result getting success.

when result's come to the " Run test " task.

It will show one Error in "Run test task log ". which i have attached below screenshot.

[image]

Please check my step and help me in this issue.
i'm facing this issue since last few days.

Comment: Which task throw this error, is `npm test`? If yes, are you certain that `npm install` is occurring in the same directory as the task which runs `npm run test`? To get more info, please share the screenshot for your build error.

Comment: Hi,
I edited my question and explained my configuration and error screenshot.
so Please check error and help me.

Comment: If possible, please check if this ticket give any help: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/5152

Comment: Hi, I have change phantomjs to chromeHeadless. it working fine for publish test result with test result is 42 total tests - 23 passed and 19 failed result show on test tab, but  in test pipe line getting error Like:  " task result: Failed" , " ##[error]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1 " 
please help me what would be wrong.

Comment: I have comment all failed test cases and run the build it work fine.
I have one question.
if any single test case is fail then build also fails ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as of now phantomjs is no longer support now, it is deprecated 
i have used 'ChromeHeadless' browser instead of 'Phantomjs' then it's worked fine for me.

if any test case is failed also build will be failed. so u can solved all case then it will work.

if anyone get this issue Please make changes as per above it will helpful.